# How can I split a variable and display in a specific format in pyspark with sparksql or data frames?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Eg- 
Dataset, this is csv file-

```
Name       ,  Country,  Income
Alan Turing,  UK,       1000
James Clark,  US,       5000
```

I would like to perform some transformation on Country and Income, but display the Name as

Name
A Turing
J Clark

Comment: What transformation you want to make for income?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with Python and asked about dataframes, you could use pandas [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['Alan Turing',  'UK',       1000],
['James Clark',  'US',       5000]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Income'])
df['Name'] = df.Name.str.replace('(\w)\w* (\w+)', r'\1 \2', regex=True)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
Name Country  Income
0  A Turing      UK    1000
1   J Clark      US    5000
```

The pattern `(\w)\w* (\w+)` is a regex that captures the first letter of the name and the (whole) last name. Then it replaces the string by the first letter of the name and the last name `r'\1 \2'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,concat,lit
myValues = [('Alan Turing','UK',1000),('James Clark','US',5000)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['Name','Country','Income'])
df.show()
+-----------+-------+------+
|       Name|Country|Income|
+-----------+-------+------+
|Alan Turing|     UK|  1000|
|James Clark|     US|  5000|
+-----------+-------+------+
df = df.withColumn('Name', concat(split(df['Name'], ' ')[0].substr(0,1), lit(' '), split(df['Name'], ' ')[1]))
df.show()
+--------+-------+------+
|    Name|Country|Income|
+--------+-------+------+
|A Turing|     UK|  1000|
| J Clark|     US|  5000|
+--------+-------+------+
```

This code above will fail if the name is `Alan Turing Müller`. Following code is more robust -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, instr, length
myValues = [('Alan Turing Müller','UK',1000),('James Clark','US',5000)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['Name','Country','Income'])
df.show()
+------------------+-------+------+
|              Name|Country|Income|
+------------------+-------+------+
|Alan Turing Müller|     UK|  1000|
|       James Clark|     US|  5000|
+------------------+-------+------+
df = df.withColumn('Name', concat(df['Name'].substr(0,1),df['Name'].substr(instr(df['Name'],' '),length(df['Name'])-instr(df['Name'],' ')+1)))
df.show()
+---------------+-------+------+
|           Name|Country|Income|
+---------------+-------+------+
|A Turing Müller|     UK|  1000|
|        J Clark|     US|  5000|
+---------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton this helps :)